# How to add stroke to just bottom side of Material button?

Tags: android, material-design, materialbutton

[image: I want to achieve this]

**I want to achieve this button.**

I Tried to add layer-list drawable background.

- Doesn't work in case of MaterialButton.
- In case of normal button it    also doesn't work because My AppTheme
  is Material Theme. So normal    Button also behaves like Material
  Button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `MaterialButton` for a custom `drawable Background` like this, said in it's [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton):

> Do not use the `android:background` attribute. `MaterialButton` manages
> its own `background` `drawable`, and setting a new `background` means
> `MaterialButton` can no longer guarantee that the new attributes it
> introduces will function properly. If the default `background` is
> changed, `MaterialButton` cannot guarantee well-defined behavior.

---

Anyways, I designed the custom `Background` `drawable` for a normal `Androidx Button` for you.

In your `activity_main.xml` you define the `Button` with the attribute `android:background="@drawable/custom_shape"` you will insert the `drawable` we define later:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Collect"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_shape"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the mentioned `drawable` called `custom_shape.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffc9a1"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="5dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#f7791e" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

The final result look pretty close to your wished Button:

[image: Button with custom Background]